# How to avoid crosswalk project to download the runtime from Google Play?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I'm using crosswalk with **embedded mode** for Ionic project. This work perfect on my device (Lenovo A680 with ARM).

But for some device such as: Asus Zenfone (x86), SamSung Galaxy Tab (ARM), it prompt me to download the *Crosswalk Project Runtime* from Google Play before I can use my app.

I saw that when run `ionic build android`, it will auto generate for me two _.apk_which are `android_x86_debug.apk` and `android_arm_debug.apk` (same with release mode).

You know that, Asus Zenfone is run on x86, so I install the `android_x86_debug.apk` for it, but when the app started, it still prompt me to download the Crosswalk Runtime. This problem also occur in some `arm` device like SamSung Galaxy Tab if I installed the `android_arm_debug.apk` for it.

P/s: It is too weird that some other ASUS Zenfone 5 (x86 too) can run without require user to download the runtime library.

Can anyone met this case before? I have no idea about this.

#### Here is my `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="14+"/>
<preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect"/>
<preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded"/>
```

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution? I'm on the same boat.

Comment: Do you have Cordova plugin sqlite installed?

Comment: No. Out of the blue some devices start to ask for Crosswalk. It's great to have a small apk footprint but the app start asking for it after update.

Comment: I solved my problem by extract the apk file, view the lib folder. If there is more than 1 folder inside `lib` folder, some device won't know what to use and it will ask to download. Try to remove all inside the `lib` folder (eg. armv7, x86,..) if they are not necessary, and left again one folder. That's my way

Comment: Good to know! Many thanks!